Does magic that quickens healing help with damage dealt by Heart's Blood?
Heart's Blood rote reads as such.

An initiate of Prime can easily sense
the flow of Quintessence through his own body — his life energy.
This energy flows from the Tellurian, through the Life Pattern
and back out to rejoin the cosmos. Each point corresponds to a
health level, the last three on beyond Incapacitated and their
loss resulting in death
In desperate times, mages skilled in Prime — typically
the Celestial Chorus and the Verbena — can push themselves
beyond their limits and “give ’til it hurts,” taking the additional
health levels as points of Quintessence above and beyond what
is stored in their Avatars. Such damage may only be healed by
time and bed rest, not magic, so most mages will usually only risk
the Bruised health level. Mages of the Chorus, however, have
burned themselves out in acts of martyrdom to perform one last
holy miracle, while Verbena with low Avatar ratings often use
their Bruised health level as a power reservoir, considering the
sacrifice of heart’s blood more holy than the spiritual energy
used by most mages.

The text mentions

Such damage may only be healed by time and bed rest, not magic

In this case does the Rapid Healing Rote which quickens the healing process rather than healing work or is it ineffective due to the fact that it is magic?
Rapid Healing rote for reference

With proper care, the caster can heal from bad
injuries in a matter of days, rather than months. For
each success, the Mage can heal a level of nonaggravated
damage at a maximum rate of one per day.
Aggravated damage is only healed on a successful
Stamina roll (difficulty 8) and does get a dice pool
penalty due to the injuries, as well as needing to spend
quintessence. This cannot heal any injury that is truly
impossible to heal naturally: if a character loses a limb,
this rote is of little help.


No, it precludes any and all magic
You found the exact correct spot. It says clearly, that you can not use magic to fix the pattern damage you did to yourself by spending your health levels as a replacement for quintessence. That includes assisting normal healing just as much as using Time to spend time faster.
The Bruised level heals within a day, so a good night's sleep fixes that.

The argument would be "when is something magic", is it "healed by magic" if you use magic to carry a jug of water to the patient? What about if you use magic to feed the patient? Does it make a difference whether an iron lung would be powered by steam/electricity or by magic to consider it "healed by magic"? Or what about if you use magic to carry nutrients to parts of the body that need it? Point is, supporting (with magic or not) the body in what it needs to do probably should probably be rewarded somehow (its just better bed rest), but crucially not familiar with the settings+system.

@DavidMulder in Mage the pattern of something is the underlying metaphysical construct which supports this thing. Pattern damage is damage to the very essence of the thing. Expediating natural healing to fix pattern damage makes about as much impact as putting a band aid on an arm that has a broken bone. Technically a band aid helps healing. But it does not addresses the root cause of the injury.

@DavidMulder also "Does it make a difference whether an iron lung would be powered by steam/electricity or by magic to consider it "healed by magic"?" it could very well be powered by steam or electricity (maybe even both) and still be magic. The setting does prominently include technomagic. In general any human who has an Awakened Avatar can twist the universe at least in small ways to suits its whims. That's what magic is in Mage. The way they do it - chanting, or runic markings, or hypertech, or mad science is just the vehicle by which they enact their will on the universe.

@VLAZ Fair enough, I probably got 'mislead' by the mention of 'bed rest', which made it very much sound like a physical thing

@DavidMulder good night's sleep and bed rest are references to natural healing as in no magical assistance at all.
